# What is the meaning of matrix type in opencv?

Tags: opencv, matrix, types

This question might sound very stupid but i always have hard time understanding the concept of matrix type such as `CV_8UC1, CV_8UC2, CV_32F, CV_64F`. What exactly does this mean and how do they differ from each other? Can someone explain me in simple terms? I read the opencv documentation but its still not clear. Thanks

Comment: See: Mat::depth in http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

Comment: From the link in Emmad's comment "A primitive OpenCV data type is one of unsigned char, bool, signed char, unsigned short, signed short, int, float, double, or a tuple of values of one of these types, where all the values in the tuple have the same type. Any primitive type from the list can be defined by an identifier in the form **CV_<bit-depth>{U|S|F}C(<number_of_channels>)**, for example: uchar ~ CV_8UC1, 3-element floating-point tuple ~ CV_32FC3, and so on."

Answer (score 4):

Number is how many bytes the matrix values have.
U symbol marks unsigned int.
F marks floating point
Therefore:
8U is equivalent of `unsigned char` in c++
32F is equivalent of `float`
64F is equivalent of `double`

C1, C2, C3 mean, how many `C`hannels each value has.

Therefore, if You want to use color (RGB) image, that has intensity values integer from 0 to 255, You use CV_8UC3. If You want to do a matrix multiplication on random, floating point matrices, You use CV_32F or CV_64F matrices.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Suffix `CN` means the matrix has `N` channels.

And check out the following links for more info:

- http://ninghang.blogspot.hk/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html